# How to create this scrollable grid like view with Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need to implement az auditorium viewer and seat selector screen with Material-UI, but I do not found any similar control.

What would you suggest to implement this screen with?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was bored enough so I build a quick example for you, it uses some components from [TicToc Tutorial from React.com](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html):

It uses `<Grid>` from Material-UI to organize the columns, then, you build each row using:
`<Board init={4} end={9}/>` where init and end `props` determine the cardinals and length of each row.

So, with this combinations you can build the layout you wish, you'll find the way yourself:

[image: Broken cinema]

As the js file:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';



class Board extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      squares: Array(Math.abs(1+this.props.end-this.props.init)).fill(null),
    };
  }

  handleClick(i) {
    const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
    squares[i] = squares[i] ? 0 : 1;
    this.setState({squares: squares});
  }

  renderSquare(i) {
    return (
      <Square
        value={this.state.squares[i]}
        onClick={() => this.handleClick(i) }
        id={i}
      />
    );
  }

  renderBoard(init,end) {
    var line = [];
    for(let i=init; i<=end; i++) {
      line.push(this.renderSquare(i));
    }
    return (
        line
    );
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Grid container>
          {this.renderBoard(this.props.init,this.props.end)}
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
class Square extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button
        className="square"
        onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}
        style={{ backgroundColor: this.props.value ? 'green' : 'black'}}
      >
      {this.props.id}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class Scene extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs="6">
          <Board init={1} end={11}/>
          <Board init={2} end={11}/>
          <Board init={3} end={10}/>
          <Board init={4} end={9}/>
          <Board init={2} end={11}/>
          <Board init={0} end={11}/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs="6">
          <Board init={10} end={1}/>
          <Board init={6} end={12}/>
          <Board init={9} end={13}/>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}
export default Scene;
```

The App.css file:

```css
.square {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  float: left;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  margin-right: -1px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 34px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Hi @yuri! I would have a freelance offer for you. Are you interested? Please contact me on Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/kukoda.janos